# How to load custom XML feed with Jsoup?

Tags: java, http, get, jsoup, document

I have a Java-method that gets a feed-document (via http) and then parses the feed (which is not of-type JSON or XML).
This is the method:

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getFeed(String type)
{
    String feed = "";
    String address = "";
    Document file;

    /**
     * FEED URLs-------\/
     */
    switch (type) {
        case "news":
            address = "https://[domain]/svc/feeds/news/6001?subtree=false&imagesize=medium-square";
            break;
        case "events":
            address = "http://[domain]/svc/feeds/events/6001?subtree=true&imagesize=medium-square&from=%5bfromDate%5d&to=%5btoDate";
    }
    try {
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(address)).openConnection();
        //TODO: @Test
        //----------------------------\/--THIS ONE WILL CAUSE ERRORS!!
        file = (Document)connection.getContent();
        connection.disconnect();

        //OUTPUT
        feed = file.getElementsByAttribute("pre").text();
        stream = new StringReader(feed);
    } catch (Exception e) {}

    //BEGIN PARSING\\//--THEN OUTPUT//\\
    try {
        return parse();
    } catch (FeedParseException e) {}
    //de-fault
    return null;
}
```

It's not working; saying that object:'file' caused `NullPointerException`.
So how do I increase my precision in debugging something which seems to me to be non-Open-Source.

P.S.: I'm not testing the "events" case so don't worry about the GET-parameters there.

---

here's my stack-trace:
[image]

I don't see how it helps though...

Comment: anyone??............................

Comment: Could you paste a bit of the stack trace ? Also I would recommend confirming that a connection has been made successfully. e.g. What is the value of `value.getResponseCode()` ?

Comment: You're not actually parsing the Document with Jsoup. Try doing something like `file = Jsoup.connect(address).get();`. Also post your stack trace, and mabe a bit more of your code, as your code looks a little strange to me.

Comment: I'll try the Jsoup method; thanks Jonas!

Comment: The code is hiding exceptions. At least log them or throw a RuntimeException. Your issue can be there.

Comment: Great, I got this exception: UnsupportedMimeTypeException "Unhandled content type. Must be text/XML/..."

Comment: But I thought Jsoup could handle html-files?! I'm confused...

Comment: @Stephan so what should I do?????

Comment: @Olivier10178 Disable content type checking with `ignoreContentType` method. See the update in my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35935879/363573.

Comment: @Stephan SUCCESS!! thanks alot man

Comment: @Olivier10178 You're welcome. Today I hope you've learned to **never ever** hide exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass to Jsoup the `URL` object directly.

Instead of:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(address)).openConnection();
//TODO: @Test
//----------------------------\/--THIS ONE WILL CAUSE ERRORS!!
file = (Document)connection.getContent();
connection.disconnect();
```

do

```
file = Jsoup //
          .connect(address) //
          .timeout( 10 * 1000) //
          .ignoreContentType(true) //
          .get();
```

**Jsoup 1.8.3**

Comment: @Olivier10178 Can you add the stack trace to your post please?